# Multiple Inheritance with Interfaces

Tags: c#, design-patterns, interface, multiple-inheritance

I was watching a video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Huj3Jbz-NFw) and here is a picture from it.

[image]

My question is: Couldn't class AB be created without using interfaces Such that you hold the A and B objects inside and call them? What information am I throwing away when I say that interface can be ignored.

Comment: This is a common question when people first learn about interfaces.  An interface is a contract, if you only have one object using the contract then its hard to see the value, but when you have hundreds its much easier.

Comment: @paqogomez Do you know of any good resources that may illustrate this? Or are most scaled down as seen above?

Comment: Any good c# book will walk you through interfaces and discuss their merits.  My experience is to just use them until you understand why they allow you to code better.

Comment: @paqogomez thank you :) I will check out a textbook to see if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By implementing `IA` and `IB` class `AB` can be used wherever `IA` or `IB` are expected:

```
void doSomethingWithIA(IA item)
{
  item.AMethod();
}

...

AB ab = new AB();
doSomethingWithIA(ab);
```

If `AB` had just the same Method names as `IA` and `IB` `doSomethingWithIA()` would not accept it as argument.

Comment: I see the value in that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the `AB` class *could* contain the `A` and the `B` objects as `class members`.
The example in the image is kinda hard to picture in a 'real' example.

I ususaly go after the rule:
*If it IS a [type], inherit.

If it HAS a [type], member.*

Example.
Cat **is** an Animal, so Cat inherit from Animal.
Cat **has** a Tail, so Tail is a member of Cat.

And as C# do not let you inherit from multiple classes, you have to use interfaces.

Cat **is** an Animal, but it also **is** a Trickster, and thats two different types.
So it implements the `IAnimal` and `ITrickster` interfaces!

Comment: Maybe I don't fully understand the IS and HAS relationships. What is the most important thing about an IS relationship?

Comment: "Cat is an Animal" -> Any Animal method or property applies to Cat. "Cat has a Tail" -> the methods and properties of Tail apply to part of Cat, but not all of Cat

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is why do we even need an interface.

One of the reasons I could think of is reducing the coupling between the classes. 
In Test driven development, interfaces help you lot to replace with mock objects.

Check these links for more information.
[Why do we need interfaces in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528420/why-do-we-need-interfaces-in-java)
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/8edbf675-6375-4735-997e-bd7bce58f115/why-do-we-need-interfaces?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: The second link helped immensely. Thank you so much