# Why shouldn't i change the interface method names when implementing them?

Tags: java

Say I'm using a Runnable interface,

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // some code

    }
};
```

If the run () method in Runnable interface is empty , why should we use @Override and same name for the method in our code instead of just using a random name for our implementation like ,

```
Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void myRun() {
        // some code

    }
};
```

*The question might seem dumb but I'm  a newbie to programming!*

Comment: "Implementing an interface" is, by definition, "having all the methods that the interface requires you to have". If you only have a `myRun` method, then you are not implementing `Runnable`, because `Runnable` requires that you have a `run` method.

Comment: As for why we use `@Override`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/212614/should-we-override-an-interfaces-method-implementation

Comment: In addition any object which implements the `Runnable` interface can be passed to as a parameter to a method which accepts runnable. A `Thread` constructor for example can be passed a runnable instance and knows to call `Runnable::run` after initialising the new thread (on `Thread::start`).

Comment: Why would you want to change the name of the method?  Remembering that the caller only sees the names in the Interface, what does the name change buy you other than confusion, even if you could do it?

Comment: @Sweeper  ,You said Runnable requires me to have a run method. Why does Runnable require me to have a run method is my question? After all interface methods are empty right ?

Comment: @MonsJoseph Because it's declared `interface Runnable { void run(); }`? The whole point of interfaces is so that other code can be sure that things have certain methods that they can definitely call. Maybe you haven't understand the benefits of using interfaces? See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface

Comment: If we don't enforce this requirement then interfaces would be quite useless (see second half of my answer). We would be using `Object`s all the time. And if you are wondering why we need interfaces in the first place, see the above link, and maybe also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528420/why-do-we-need-interfaces-in-java/17163473).

Comment: Think of an interface as a contract. When a class implements Runnable, the class must implement the run () method, exactly as the interface states.

Answer (score 2):

Runnable has only one method, thus, you may be tempted to think the method name is irrelevant. But most interfaces have more than one method. For example, [`java.util.Iterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html) which has 2 (well, 4, but 2 of those have default impls so you don't *need* to implement those. Point is, 2 that you must implement).

So, let's say that instead of naming your two methods `next` and `hasNext`, you name them `jill` and `jane` instead.

How is the compiler or any caller supposed to figure out which one performs the hasNext job and which one performs the next job? Look at the signatures? What if your interface has 2 different methods with the exact same signature?

Not possible. That's why the names need to match: They are used to look this up.

Yes, if the interface has just the one name you'd think the compiler/caller can just go: Yeah, well, the one and only method it has, that's the one. But that's not how it works - language design is simpler if you avoid making exceptions just for simplified cases.

Note that java has lambda syntax, which only works when an interface has one method, and which omit the method name entirely, as well as the argument types. Instead of your myRun method you could write this too:

```
Runnable r = () -> /* some code */;
```

No `new Runnable() { public void myRun`, and no `}}` required. If myRun had arguments, you don't even need to add their types, just their names. For example, `Comparator`, which has arguments:

long form:

```
Comparator<String> lengthComparator = new Comparator<String>() {
    @Override public int compare(String a, String b) {
        return a.length() - b.length();
    }
};
```

can be written much shorter:

```
Comparator<String> lengthComparator = (a, b) -> a.length() - b.length();
```

Answer (score 1):

Think about what it means to "implement an interface". If I have a variable of an interface type, I can call any method defined in the interface on that variable. For example, for the `Runnable` interface:

```
interface Runnable {
    void run();
}
```

If I have a variable of type `Runnable`, I know I can call `run` on it:

```
Runnable r = ...;
r.run(); // I can guarantee this will work, because whatever "..." evaluates to, implements Runnable
```

So when you implement `Runnable`, you are really just saying that "this class has a `run` method". The Java compiler also checks that what you are saying is true, that the class actually has a `run` method. Saying false things about your class, intuitively, should not be allowed, right?

We can also think about what would happen if you were allowed to implement `Runnable`, but not provide a `run` method, then you would not be 100% sure that any variable of type `Runnable` has a `run` method.

```
class TrueRunnable implements Runnable {
    @Override public void run() {}
}
class FakeRunnable implements Runnable { // suppose this is allowed
    public void myRun() {}
}

...

Runnable r;
if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
    r = new TrueRunnable()
} else {
    r = new FakeRunnable(); 
}
// does r have a run method? Maybe.
```

Then interfaces would not be very useful, because you are not 100% sure whether *any* `Object` has *any* method anyway.

```
Object r;
if (new Random().nextBoolean()) {
    r = new TrueRunnable()
} else {
    r = new FakeRunnable(); 
}
// does r have a run method? Maybe.
```

So in that case we would lose the whole point of using interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

As to why an interface implementation method has to have the same name as the declaration method name in the interface , i think it boils down to allowing Java compiler to understand which method actually implements the interface. Otherwise its impossible for the Java compiler to know.
Another solution could have been to use a qualifier name in an annotation to signal which is  the implementation method something like this.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    void sayHello();
}
```

and

```
public class Hello implements MyInterface {

   @Implements("MyInterface.sayHello")
   public void someOtherName() {
       print("Hello World);
   }

}
```

This approach is not valid , but could have been an alternative if Java creators wanted to allow users to declare different names for interface implementation methods. I think this approach is uglier and prone to errors though.

Also this problem does not exist when using lambda expressions where the compiler can understand whats happening without the code writer having to specify the name of the interface method. Note that this only applies to functional interfaces.