# Java ConstraintValidator Purpose

Tags: java, spring-boot, bean-validation

I am trying to understand the purpose of Java's [`ConstraintValidator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html) interface.

It's an interface, however how does it make coding more quick or more efficient? Trying to understand benefits of using it with our team.

From Baeldung's [Spring MVC Custom Validation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator):

> The validation class implements the ConstraintValidator interface, and
> must also implement the isValid method; it's in this method that we
> defined our validation rules.
>
> Naturally, we're going with a simple validation rule here in order to
> show how the validator works.
>
> ConstraintValidator defines the logic to validate a given constraint
> for a given object. Implementations must comply with the following
> restrictions:

**Code Example:**

```
public class ContactNumberValidator implements 
  ConstraintValidator<ContactNumberConstraint, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ContactNumberConstraint contactNumber) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String contactField,
      ConstraintValidatorContext cxt) {
        return contactField != null && contactField.matches("[0-9]+")
          && (contactField.length() > 8) && (contactField.length() < 14);
    }

}
```

Comment: You create a `ConstraintValidator` implementation as part of a custom constraint annotation.

Comment: Are you asking the more fundamental question as to [why Java has interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3528420/12567365) in the first place? (If so, I would say its not primarily to "make coding more quick or more efficient").

Comment: Minor point: If your platform supports it, you may want to use the newer [Jakarta API](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/webprofile/9/apidocs/jakarta/validation/constraintvalidator) instead of the older [javax API](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/ConstraintValidator.html). See [Maven](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.validation/jakarta.validation-api) - this is used by the latest versions of [Hibernate Validator](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator/7.0.4.Final).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose is to define custom validation-logic for a custom annotation.

#### Purpose of `ConstraintValidator`

In the given example the `ConstraintValidator` implementation can be used as annotation on your property (assuming `ContactNumberConstraint` is a `public @interface`, defined as annotation for fields):

```
@ContactNumberConstraint
String contactField;
```

As such shorthand it combines several validations like otherwise have to be listed separately:

```
@NotNull  // contactField != null
@Pattern(regexp="[0-9]+" )  // contactField.matches("[0-9]+")
@Length(min=9, max=13)  // (contactField.length() > 8) && (contactField.length() < 14)
String contactField;
```

Here the implemented `ConstraintValidator` is used to validate the property, for example if used as parameter (in a REST-controller, or any other validated method).

#### How does it make coding more quick or more efficient?

With this pair of annotation and validator you can simply declare a rather complex validation at any field or class by just annotating the field - by **adding one line**. Spring would care about initiating the validation. It executes the logic defined in validator and handles errors.

This predefined validation component as pair of annotation-interface and validator can be reused easily at many places (reduce code duplication), it can be composed and allows giving complex validations a name (using an expressive annotation name). Through its declarative way (annotation) it is loosely coupled.

More on benefits of [Java Bean Validation](https://beanvalidation.org/) (JSR 303, 380)

#### See also

- [Validation in Java Applications - DZone Java](https://dzone.com/articles/validation-in-java-applications)
- [Java Bean Validation Basics | Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/javax-validation)